# Selecting case when a string is matched

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to check the storage path of an Excel file and save it to different locations based on a input provided. I have a Vlookup function to get the input which works.

When I use a case statement the control jumps over all cases even though the value is met.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

    Dim strName As String
    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ActiveSheet
    Dim StrPath As String
    Dim myFirstColumn As Long
    Dim myLastColumn As Long
    Dim myColumnIndex As Long
    Dim myFirstRow As Long
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim SaveLocation As String
    Dim myTableArray As Range

    myLookupValue = wsA.Range("B2").Value
    myFirstColumn = 2
    myLastColumn = 8
    myColumnIndex = 7
    myFirstRow = 19
    myLastRow = 78


    With Worksheets("List")
        Set myTableArray = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), 
    .Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn))
    End With
    myVlookupResult = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myLookupValue, myTableArray, 
    myColumnIndex, False)
    strName = wsA.Range("B5").Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:=123456
    wsA.Range("A6").Clear ' new line for date and time
    wsA.Range("A6").Value = wsA.Range("G5").Value ' new line for date and time
    Range("A6").Select
        With Selection.Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Visible = True
            ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Enabled = False
        End If
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=123456
    SaveLocation = myVlookupResult
    Select Case SaveLocation
    Case "MCT"
    StrPath = "MCT Gates"
    Case "BG"
    StrPath = "Secondary Screening Gates"
    End Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs 

      Filename:= StrPath & "/For Approval/" & strName & ".xlsm" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=123456
    End Sub
```

Comment: could you check for case-sensitive equality and try after trimming the SaveLocation value

Comment: i.e. use “Select Case UCase(SaveLocation)” or “Select Case WorksheetFunction.Trim(UCase(SaveLocation))”

Comment: “Select Case WorksheetFunction.Trim(UCase(SaveLocation))” this works perfect. thanks for the help.

Comment: @N.Almeida, you are welcome